# Why are there 3 solutions in this trigonometric equation $sin\theta = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

my question is Why are there 3 solutions in this trigonometric equation $sin\theta = 0$? I thought since the range for the angle is between 0 and 360 it has 2 solutions? I tried and I have got 2 solutions which are 0, and 180 but apparently there is 1 more solution. Can someone please explain this and if you can, also tell me what do I do if I obtain a negative angle? For example in this equation $tan(\theta-50)=-1.7$, I solved and got a negative angle, how do I proceed to the next step? Please help Thank you!

Comment: **Where** do you need your solutions to exist? Without restriction, the equation $\;\sin\theta=0\;$ has infinite solutions: $\;\theta=k\pi\;$ , for any integer $\;k\;$ .

Comment: There are only $2$ solutions in $[0,360)$  If you increase the interval you can get more.

Comment: In $[0^{\circ}, 360^{\circ}]$ there are 3 solutions: $0^{\circ}, 180^{\circ}, 360^{\circ}$

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is defined to be in $(-\frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{2})$ if you want an answer in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})\cup(\frac {\pi}{2},\pi)$ you can add $\pi$ to your result.

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak why 360? i thought only 0, and 180?

Comment: @Tfue Think about the unit circle. After you rotate by $360º$, you end up in exactly the same place as before.

Comment: @TobyMak yes but we do not need to though, sin is positive therefore the angles located at quadrants 1 and 2 right? why do i need to add 360?

Comment: @Tfue It depends on the domain – whether you include $360º$ or not.

Comment: @TobyMak but why do we include 360 in the range of 0 to 360 for the angle? i thought there are 2 solutions every period?

Comment: @Tfue What's your domain first?

Comment: @TobyMak $0<\theta>360$ my teacher said there are 3 solutions in this one, which are 0, 180 and 360

Comment: @Tfue Teachers can be wrong. $360$ is not greater than $360$. If you wanted to have 3 solutions, you would need $0 ≤ \theta ≤ 360$.

Comment: @TobyMak yea the range that u have written, but how and why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85579/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-tfue).